# String.intern is it the same just copy an object reference in Java?

Tags: java, string-interning

Is doing:

```
String a = new String();
String b = a;
```

and doing:

```
String a = new String();
String b = a.intern();
```

is the same ?

Actually, the reference are all the same if I test:

```
String a = new String("te");
String b = a.intern();
String c = a;
String d = "t" + "e";
System.out.print(a.equals(b));
System.out.print(b.equals(c));
System.out.print(a.equals(d));
```

Cause the String will ever be in the String pool ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `equals` tests aren't checking for *references* - they're checking for *string equality*. You should be using `==` to check the references for *identity*. Effectively, you're making the common rookie Java mistake *in reverse* - usually people use `==` when they should be using `equals`. In this particular case, all of those will print `false`, because there are two String objects involved (the string from the constant pool, and the new string created in the first line). If we call these #1 and #2 respectively, we end up with:

```
a = #2 // Explicit call to string constructor
b = #1 // intern will return reference to constant pool instance
c = #2 // Direct assignment
d = #1 // Equivalent string constant, so reference to constant pool instance
```

However, you may find this interesting:

```
String a = "te";
String b = a.intern();
String c = "t" + "e";
System.out.println(a == b); // true
System.out.println(a == c); // true
```

`"te"` and `"t" + "e"` are equal constant string expressions, so end up as references to a single string, and calling `intern` on a string already in the literal pool won't have any effect.

Comment: but 
String a = "te";
String c = "t" + "e";
System.out.println(a == c); // true

Comment: Works also. So It's not necessary to intern the string in the pool ?

Comment: String literals are automatically interned, and "t" + "e" is compiled to "te" by the Java compiler.

Answer (score 1):

To start off: `"t" + "e"` is a String literal, because it will be optimised by the compiler. This string literal is also used in this line:

```
String a = new String("te");
```

Now, the `String(String)` constructor makes a physical copy of the String. So, this means that  `a` and `d` are **not** the same object.

Then: `String.equals(String)` **compares** two Strings. It says if the **content** was equal and not the object. This means you might have two different String objects which have the same sequence of characters, which will make the `String.equals(String)` return `true`.

`String.intern()` puts the String in the String pool, if it isn't yet in it. But this method **can't** change the object itself. So this code example will print false:

```
String literal = "lit";
String nonLiteral = "abclit".substring(3); // equals "lit"
nonLiteral.intern(); // "lit" was already in the String pool
                     // but `nonLiteral` is still `nonLiteral`
System.out.println(literal == nonLiteral); // false
```

However if you would do this: it will return true:

```
String literal = "lit";
String nonLiteral = "abclit".substring(3); // equals "lit"
nonLiteral = nonLiteral.intern(); // "lit" was already in the String pool and
                                  // it will return the object `literal`.
                                  // Now the value is replaced.
System.out.println(literal == nonLiteral); // true
```

Comment: See my comment on fge's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using equals doesn't test the equality of the references. It tests the equality of the contents of the String. You need to use `==` to test the equality of the references.

To answer your question, no, it's not the same. The first snippet assigns two references (a and b) to the same String. The second one creates a String, assigns it to a, then interns the String and assigns the String that the intern pool returns to b. a and b could thus refer to two different String instances (and certainly will, because the empty String is in the pool for sure, thus intern() will not return the STring referred to by a, but will returned the pooled empty String)

Answer (score 0):

If that string value has already been interned from a different `String` instance, `intern()` will return the earlier instance.